# What should be done to export sparql query results in protege 5.2 to excel?

Tags: sparql, owl, protege

I have a huge query result. Its difficult to read it in Protege 5.2. Any  idea on how I can export the results to excel or any other software?

Comment: What format is your result in now?  RDF/XML?  Turtle?

Comment: @MarkMiller She is using Protege which contains a SPARQL tab which shows the results in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/protegeproject/sparql-query-plugin/issues/2), there is no explicit export button or the like yet, but you can use the same like in most applications to copy text:

1. select the corresponding rows or select all with `CTRL + A`
2. use `CTRL + C` to copy the rows
3. use `CTRL + V` to paste the results in the current application, e.g. in Excel

Comment: This is just giving me the links on excel. I want the required lines in a table format

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your problem now. If you copy the rows from the table in the Protege 5 SPARQL query tab, then it will be tab-separated data and this can be pasted into an Excel sheet. I tried it by myself and it works perfectly. What do you mean by "links"?

Comment: http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#Has http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#Function
http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#Has http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#Function
I am getting it like this on excel. I want the words "Has", "Function" etc alone

Comment: Ok, but that's a different question! This is the task of your SPARQL query. The only reason why you don't see the URIs is that Protege has some rendering enabled. But the result of your SPARQL query are OWL entities which are identified by URIs.